# Can one who died at the age of seventy five be considered to have died with a "Misas Neshikah"?

Tags: talmud-gemara

The Gemara in [Moed Katan 28a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.28a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that if one dies suddenly it is called a "מיתה חטופה", but if he has reached the age of "Gevuros", which is eighty, than it is called a "מיתת נשיקה". If one dies suddenly at the age of seventy five, would it be possible to include it in מיתת נשיקה?

Comment: Considering that Chazal say that resha'im are considered to be meisim even in their lifetimes and Sarah is a rare person to be considered to have fulfilled "all" of her days (further discussion in the Reishis Chochmah shaar hayir'ah on something similar, I can't recall where off the top of my head), I feel like the measurement of a person's years vis-a-vis a concept like this is somewhat more delicate than a simple age.